# Nexus 5 volume-down button stuck, cannot boot non-safe mode

Tags: recovery-mode, nexus-5, safe-mode, volume-buttons

I got a bit of liquid onto my phone, and now the volume-down button on my Nexus 5 doesn't seem to work.  The button itself doesn't bother me much, but every time I reboot the phone, it goes into recovery mode, and it appears that it can only be booted into safe mode.

What can I do to stop it from always booting into safe mode?

Comment: Is because of button or some sort of flash you did ?

Comment: @user4847410, just the button; i'm curious whether disassembling the phone and disconnecting the buttons would make it work again, or whether they do apply some sort of idle resistance, making the phone not turn on at all if the buttons are just missing.